# Convert a Variable To a Propery Variable Using Reflection

Tags: vb.net, class, reflection, types, typeconverter

I am trying to convert

```
 Public Class TestClass

    Public FirstName As String 

 End Class
```

To

```
 Public Class AnotherClass 
        Public Property FirstName As String 

 End Class
```

I wrote a function that will convert the member of one class to member of another class, so if I pass some class type that has `Public Property LastName AS  String` it will convert it to (for instance) `AnotherClass Type` variable and I will be able to get the value so I am happy here.

```
 Public Shared Function ConvertModelToValidationDataModel(Of T)(ByVal oSourceObject As Object) As T
        Dim oSourceObjectType As Type
        Dim oSourceObjectProperties() As PropertyInfo

        Dim oDestinationObjectProperties() As PropertyInfo

        Dim oDestinationObject As Object
        Dim oDestinationObjectType As Type

        oDestinationObject = Activator.CreateInstance(Of T)()

        oDestinationObjectType = GetType(T)

        oDestinationObjectProperties = oDestinationObjectType.GetProperties

        oSourceObjectType = oSourceObject.GetType()
        oSourceObjectProperties = oSourceObjectType.GetProperties()

        If Not oSourceObjectProperties Is Nothing Then

            If oSourceObjectProperties.Count > 0 Then

                For Each oDestinationObjectPropertyInfo As PropertyInfo In oDestinationObjectProperties

                    For Each oSourceObjectPropertyInfo As PropertyInfo In oSourceObjectProperties

                        If oDestinationObjectPropertyInfo.Name = oSourceObjectPropertyInfo.Name Then

                            oDestinationObjectPropertyInfo.SetValue(oDestinationObject, oSourceObjectPropertyInfo.GetValue(oSourceObject, Nothing))

                        End If

                    Next
                Next
            End If
        End If

        Return oDestinationObject
    End Function
```

The problem is I want to pass `TestClass` (**the variable `FirstName` is not a property but I want it to be converted to a property variable**) and be able to convert it and get the value but for some reason it does not pass the value and obviously it looks like the **function converts it to a non-property variable of another class - not the property variable like I want it to**.

**

### Short version:

**

When I pass in a class type that has property variables (`Public Property FirstName As String`) - I get back a class of another type, all the values are passed and converted to property variables.

When I pass in class type that has variables (`Public FirstName As String`) I am not able to get the value and it does not convert it to property variable.

**Question:** Why I am not able to get the value and convert it to a property variable when passing in a class type that has a non-property variable?

Comment: Isn't that because you wrote `oSourceObjectProperties = oSourceObjectType.GetProperties()`?

Comment: Alireza is right. I think you want to `.GetFields.`

Comment: Thank you guys - I can't believe it was that obvious and I did not see it!!! The Code Soldiers!!!!!

Comment: If you have to do a lot of this sort of stuff, I strongly recommend you look at AutoMapper: http://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper/3.2.1 . This is a tool that will automate a lot of "convert from this type to that type" kinds of operations with fairly little setup.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Chris! I have not looked to deep into it but the are statements that AutoMapper seems to be taking longer to accomplish the same task. I could be wrong and please correct me if I am - but I believe working with Reflection directly may be a bit more efficient that using the AutoMapper which is a library that also uses Reflection to automate that mapping for you. This is a library I used for my current project until I was told not to use it due to this same reason. Appreciate your suggestion though!

Comment: it would have been better to add the solution as an answer rather than an edit

Comment: Thank You! I am new guy here so I appreciate your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

Thanks the guys in the comment section below for helping me visualize the fact that I was asking an object for the properties while object only had fields.

Here is the Updated Version of the function for those who interested

```
Public Shared Function ConvertModelToValidationDataModel(Of T)(ByVal oSourceObject As Object) As T
    Dim oSourceObjectType As Type
    Dim oSourceObjectFields() As FieldInfo

    Dim oDestinationObjectProperties() As PropertyInfo

    Dim oDestinationObject As Object
    Dim oDestinationObjectType As Type

    oSourceObjectType = oSourceObject.GetType()
    oSourceObjectFields = oSourceObjectType.GetFields()

    oDestinationObject = Activator.CreateInstance(Of T)()

    oDestinationObjectType = GetType(T)

    oDestinationObjectProperties = oDestinationObjectType.GetProperties

    If Not oSourceObjectFields Is Nothing Then

        If oSourceObjectFields.Count > 0 Then

            For Each oSourceObjectFieldInfo As FieldInfo In oSourceObjectFields

                For Each oDestinationObjectPropertyInfo As PropertyInfo In oDestinationObjectProperties

                    If oSourceObjectFieldInfo.Name = oDestinationObjectPropertyInfo.Name Then

                        oDestinationObjectPropertyInfo.SetValue(oDestinationObject, oSourceObjectFieldInfo.GetValue(oSourceObject))

                    End If

                Next

            Next
        End If
    End If

    Return oDestinationObject
End Function
```